# How to test Matlabs blocking uiconfirm?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, dialog

I have a class with a simple user interface and want to write unit tests for all public member functions.

One of my buttons issues a warning via dialog. I use the `uiconfirm` function and assign the result to a variable to block the function until the user confirms the dialog.

```matlab
classdef UI
    properties
        fig    matlab.ui.Figure
        button matlab.ui.control.Button
    end

    methods
        function obj = UI()
            obj.fig = uifigure();
            obj.button = uibutton(obj.fig);
            obj.button.Text = "click me";
            obj.button.ButtonPushedFcn = @(~, ~) obj.click();
        end
    end

    methods
        function click(obj)
            [~] = uiconfirm(obj.fig, "Something failed.", "Warning", ...
                "Options", {'OK'}, "Icon", "warning");
        end
    end
end
```

I use class based unit tests:

- https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/class-based-unit-tests.html

How can I test the click function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if you're familiar with Matlab [App Testing Framework](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/overview-of-app-testing-framework.html). The App Testing Framework allows you to programmatically interact with appdesigner/uifigure apps. Take a look at the component-gesture availability matrix to help accelerate your UI Testing needs. Having said that, as of today, app testing framework doesn't yet support directly interacting with blocking UI Dialog's like uiconfirm.

An obvious brute force way of solving the blocking problem is to shadow the uiconfirm function in test with your custom version that could be non-blocking. If this is an easy enough acceptable solution for you, go forward with it. However, as your app changes and scales up, the mocks might need to get complicated too and thus become hard to maintain.

With that in mind, A better approach to test your app programmatically is to use a [mocking framework](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/mocking-framework.html) to create a mock object to define the behavior of uiconfirm. The best way to achieve this is via Dependency Injection. In your case, the App could take/have a property that could store a context aware "UIConfirm [name it according to your workflow]" object . By default in a production environment, it would call the real uiconfirm command, but a “mock” or “stub” delegator could supply deterministic outputs to make the system more testable (and avoid the “blocking” dialog issue altogether) It’s certainly added overhead to do this in an otherwise simple App, but I get the sense that you value testing as much as we do!

Also please take a look at this detailed Mocking-App Testing example https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-test-that-uses-app-testing-and-mocking-frameworks.html